# A question about tensorflow's path in colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I'm going to compile something in colab, I need to know the path of tensorflow, so I ran the code:

```
import tensorflow

print(tensorflow.version)

print("\n")

print(tensorflow.path)
```

I expect to get the exact tensorflow's path. But I got a list, containing three paths, I want to know which one should I choose.

The output is shown as below:

```
1.15.2

['/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/python/keras/api/_v1', 
'/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/api/_v1', 
'/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core', '/tensorflow-1.15.2/python3.6/tensorflow_core/_api/v1']
```

Comment: Can you explain why do you need the path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the `__path__` attribute of a module may contain more than one entry, indicating locations on the disk from which module contents can be imported. Tensorflow uses this to declare top-level module contents in multiple places; you can see this in the source code [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/410852dbd24899e22f0020f9fdc9757f527dda55/tensorflow/api_template.__init__.py#L53-L63).

If you want to find the single location where a module is defined, a better approach is the [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module:

```
import inspect
import tensorflow
inspect.getsourcefile(tensorflow)
# '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py'
```

Comment: sorry I gave up colab about a month ago, so I didn't reply you on time.